# Splitting the text and writing to combo box

Tags: java, string, swing, jcombobox

It's only writes to `comboBox1`. What's the problem? Why doesn't it write to other combo boxes?

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hatice\\Desktop\\191220009_KursadBugrahan_Yapar\\src\\lab7\\konfigurasyon.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = br.readLine();
    
    while(line != null){
        String[] name = line.split("//");
        switch(name[0]){
            case "tank":
                jComboBox1.addItem(name[1]);
                break;
            case "büyücü":
                jComboBox2.addItem(name[1]);
                break;
            case "nişancı":
                jComboBox3.addItem(name[1]);
                break;
            case "suikastçi":
                jComboBox4.addItem(name[1]);
                break;
        }
        
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the input data is actually using all four cases?  Please post the input data, or a subset of it, that illustrates the problem.  Also you don't have a default case so it's possible that some of the data is simply being ignored.

Comment: My application is reading from a text file and writes to the comboBox which is corresponding.

Comment: The txt file is includes; tank//franco
savaşçı//ruby
tank//hylos
suikastçi//karina
tank//atlas
nişancı//claude
nişancı//lesley
destek//angela
nişancı//layla
suikastçi//gusion
büyücü//aurora
destek//diggie
savaşçı//martis
büyücü//alice
büyücü//odette

Comment: *My application is reading from a text file and writes to the comboBox which is corresponding* - That's the desired outcome, but have you proved it's actually using all four cases in the `switch` statement using the debugger and/or trace statements?

Comment: Given that the only one working doesn't have special chars, are you sure that it's not an encoding problem ?

Comment: I tried with no turkish characters, same problem.

Comment: @stridecolossus i tried now and it's not use other cases. What can i do?

Comment: Doesn't seem too complicated and you have ruled out possible problem with non-ASCII characters.  Maybe there is something wrong with the way you created the combo boxes?  Post that code as well.

Comment: @stridecolossus i created on JFrame form. I didn't code it.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot to change case's label when i am changing the string in txt file. The problem was like @FlorentBayle said about ASCII characters. Sorry.